# Pegar um JSON PHP Via Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Eu Tenho 3 paginas, 1-Index, onde passo algumas configurações; 2- dados_jogo.php, onde se faz uma consulta e retorna um json com os dados; 3- jogo.php, A pag onde os dados do json são exibidos são exibidos.

A minha dificuldade agora é, pegar esse dados do Json gerado pelo PHP, acho que eles estão se perdendo na hora que eu dou o Header para a outra pag, como trato melhor isso? Aqui é retornado o "Erro interno do Servidor", tem alguma forma de eu verificar esse erro?

Index

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h3 class="text-center">Antes de iniciar vamos definir algumas configurações</h3><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="config">
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success">
           <!--Div acionada via JS-->
      </div>
        <form id="jogo" action="dados_jogo.php" Method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/nome.ico"></span>
                       <input type="text" id="equipe" name="equipe1" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da primeira Equipe" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                      </div>
                      <br>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger" id="valida_equipe" role="alert">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Preencha o nome da primeira equipe
                      </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/nome.ico"></span>
                      <input type="text" id="equipe2" name="equipe2" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da Segunda Equipe" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                       </div>
                       <br>
                       <div class="alert alert-danger" id="valida_equipe2" role="alert">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Preencha o nome da segunda Equipe
                       </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="select">Selecione a Dificuldade</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="dificuldade" name="dificuldade">
                        <option value="1">Fácil</option>
                        <option value="2">Médio</option>
                        <option value="3">Difícil</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="select">Selecione o número de perguntas da rodada:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="rodada" name="rodada">
                          <option value="1">10</option>
                          <option value="2">15</option>
                          <option value="3">20</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                  <center>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="iniciar" value="Iniciar o jogo">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="refresh">Nova Tentativa</button>                  </center><br><br>
                 </form>
            <br>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Config.PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=UTF-8');
$equipe1 = $_POST['equipe1'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$equipe2 = $_POST ['equipe2'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];//Define a dificuldade das perguntas que seram selecionadas
$rodada = $_POST ['rodada'];//Número de perguntas que serão retornadas


switch ($dificuldade) {
  case '1':
    $dificuldade = "Facil";
    break;
  case '2':
    $dificuldade = "Medio";
    break;
  case '3':
    $dificuldade = "Dificil";
    break;
}

switch ($rodada) {
  case '1':
    $rodada = "10";
    break;
  case '2':
    $rodada = "15";
    break;
  case '3':
    $rodada = "20";
    break;
}
    try{
     $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=teocratico; charset=utf8","root","");
     } catch (PDOException $erro){
       echo $erro->getmessage();
       //header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
     }


$consulta = $conexao -> query ("SELECT id_pergunta, pergunta, resposta, desafio FROM perguntas
where dificuldade ='$dificuldade' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $rodada ");
    // Mostrando a Consulta
        $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $db_data = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        json_encode($db_data);
        header('Location: '.'jogo.php');//Me joga para a pagina do jogo

?>
```

Jquery/Ajax

```
function randomizar(valor) {
     return Math.floor((Math.random() * valor) + 1);
   }
   //  data = [];
     //data.push({ name: "dificuldade", value: document.getElementById("dificuldade").value});
     //data.push({ name: "quantidade", value: document.getElementById("quantidade").value});
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: "dados_jogo.php",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(returnjson) {
             var elemento = returnjson[(randomizar(returnjson.length)-1)];
             var arr = [];
             arr = returnjson;
      var arr = [];
     function exibir(){
         var elemento = arr[(randomizar(arr.length)-1)];
         document.getElementById("id_pergunta").innerHTML =      elemento.id_pergunta;
         document.getElementById("pergunta").innerHTML = elemento.pergunta;
         document.getElementById("desafio").innerHTML = elemento.desafio;
         document.getElementById("resposta_jogo").value = elemento.resposta;
     },
         error: function(returnjson) {
             alert("erro interno do servidor");

         }
     });
```

Comment: Não pode redirecionar a saída do objeto `JSON`. Usar `header('Location: '.'jogo.php');` é errado. Se precisar redirecionar, tem que redirecionar no `JavaScript`. **Afinal, pra quê mesmo esse redirecionamento, hein?**

**É simples:** O seu `JavaScript` está esperando um objeto `JSON`. Se você redireciona, a resposta do `PHP` nunca vai ser um objeto `JSON`, nem `success:`.

Comment: Esse redirecionamento provavelmente provoca o erro,"Erro interno do Servidor"

Answer (score 1):

Você falou que tem três páginas:
1-Index
2-dados_jogo.php
3-jogo.php

Ai temos 3 códigos:
1- Index
2 - Config.PHP
3 - Jquery/Ajax

Isso dificulta o entendimento do seu problema. Mas vamos lá.
O Config.php é o dados_jogo.php, e se eu entendi bem, é ele que você "pega" por ajax.
Vamos lá:
Para gerar um json para ser pego pelo jquery não precisa do header.
Você está fazendo o redirecionamento de página na página que chamada via ajax, provavelmente esse é a causa do erro **"Erro interno do Servidor"**.
Explicando, você envia uma requisição ajax e página responde com os dados do conteúdo. Acaba ai o trabalho, não deve haver redirecionamento.
Tratar isso é simples, é só redirecionar a página no javascript, usando um location.href <http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp>

Talvez você nem precise de ajax, uma requisição simples post que redireciona para outra página seja o suficiente...

Comment: Eu uso o Header, porque se eu não usar toda a ação para no dados_jogo.php, ele exibe o JSON e para por ai, você quis dizer então que eu tenho de redirecionar usando outra linguagem? Poderia dar um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: Não entendi o porquê de usar o header.Outra linguagem não, javascript, você faz o redirecinamento no client-side.